# How to create a postgresql partition table with GORM migration?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am rewriting a Golang project with Gin and Gorm. I have to use an existing Postgres database that has a partition table.

My goal is to create a Gorm migration/s in my new Gin project where I can replicate the schema I have in the existing database.

Is there a way to generate a migration by importing a given schema or executing row sql? How can I generate a partition table with a Gorm migration?